# Python Regex handling dot character

Tags: python, regex

While using regex in python I came across a scenario.
What I am trying to do is if a string has operators, I want to add space before and after the operator.

```
s = 'H>=ll<=o=wo+rl-d.my name!'
op = 'H >= ll <= o = wo + rl - d.my name!'
```

seemed pretty straight forward, so I came up with the following expression:

```
re.sub(r'((<=)|(>=)|[+-=*/])+',' \\1 ',r'H>=ll<=o=wo+rl-d.myname!')
```

but the result I am getting using this is :

```
'H >= ll <= o = wo + rl - d . my name!'
```

Its adding a space after every dot (.) encountered, even though I haven't mentioned it in my regex.

I am using python 2.7 and would really appreciate if you can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the spaces around the dot is `-`. Concrete it is `[+-=]`, which is a character class with characters from `+` until `=`, which includes `.`.

To avoid this, you must escape `-` with `\-`, e.g.

```
re.sub(r'((<=)|(>=)|[+\-=*/])+',' \\1 ',r'H>=ll<=o=wo+rl-d.myname!')
```

---

As @LaurentLAPORTE mentioned, you can also put `-` at the beginning or the end of a character class, e.g. `[-+=*/]` or `[+=*/-]` will both do the trick.

Comment: You can escape or put the "-" at the end of the range, like this `[+=*/-]`.

Comment: great stuff, mate. I would've never got this.

Answer (score 4):

So when you do a character class like:

```
[+-=]
```

The regex reads that as any character between `+` (ASCII 43) and `=` (ASCII 61). It's similar to:

```
[A-Z]
```

So you have to escape the `-`:

```
r'((<=)|(>=)|[+\-=*/])+'
```

(Or put the `-` at the end as suggested in the comments: `[+=-]`)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is very handy for analyzing regex patterns like this. You can see the problem with your pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/zDZAKf/1)

Comment: Thanks @Charles , great tip with the **Regex101** site

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify this a little bit by using a negated set:

```
import re
s = 'H>=ll<=o=wo+rl-d.my name!'
op = 'H >= ll <= o = wo + rl - d.my name!'
s = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9.])+',' \\1 ',r'H>=ll<=o=wo+rl-d.myname!')
print (s)
```

Other commenters above mentioned the reason this is happening is because the - wasn't working as you intended it to.

Comment: Thanks @A_Elric but not a scenario for negation sets, as have to replace only chosen operators. The negation set here will replace any character encountered other than the ones mentioned in your list..